# Не сохраняет данные в таблицу. flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///books.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class horror(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(50))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class teen(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(50))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class adult(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(50))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class fantasy(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(50))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class bought(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    phone = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String)
    newpost = db.Column(db.String)
    promo = db.Column(db.String)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Главная.html')


@app.route('/')
def about():
    return render_template('Страница-1.html')


@app.route('/admin')
def addbook():
    return render_template('О-нас.html')

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addpost():
    genre = request.form['genre']
    title = request.form['title']
    price = request.form['price']
    author = request.form['author']
    content = request.form['content']
    if genre == 'horror':
        horror = horror(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
        db.session.add(horror)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('Главная'))
    elif genre == 'fantasy':
        fantasy=fantasy(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
        db.session.add(fantasy)
        db.session.commit()
    elif genre == 'adult':
        adult=adult(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
        db.session.add(adult)
        db.session.commit()
    elif genre == 'teen':
        teen=teen(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
        db.session.add(teen)
        db.session.commit()



@app.route('/')
def BYE():
    return render_template('Контакты.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Ничего не могу понять. Должно работать, но не хочет. Подскажите что исправить. Спасибо,

Answer (score 1):

Сделай классы с титульной буквой **Horror**

Далее вызывай конструктор класса:

```
horror = Horror(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
```

Так же можно чуть пупростить твой код

```
if genre == 'horror':
    obj = horror(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
elif genre == 'fantasy':
    obj=fantasy(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
elif genre == 'adult':
    obj=adult(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
elif genre == 'teen':
    obj=teen(title=title, price=price, author=author, content=content)
db.session.add(obj)
db.session.commit()
return redirect(url_for('Главная'))
```